# How to remove black line in 9 patch image?

Tags: android, nine-patch

When i generate the 9 patch image at the time the image having a black line:

[image]

How to remove that black pixels?

Comment: Those black lines are part of the 9-patch standard. A 9-patch is just a PNG with black pixels in a 1-pixel border that mean certain things, and those are the lines you're seeing. If you're seeing the black lines in an application you're developing, then it probably means the graphic wasn't loaded as a 9-patch properly. We'll need to know how you're trying to use the 9-patch to figure that out.

Comment: but when i use that one my UI is not clear

Comment: We may need more words here. How did you generate it? How are you using it? What's not clear in your UI?

Comment: Did you save it as `my_image.9.png`? (mind the **9**) Or else, Android woun't recocgnize it as a 9 patch and will treat it as a normal png

Comment: i am using that 9 patch image from drawable folder. like android:background="@drawable/vtd" in xml file showing exception like index 0 and size 0 but when i run my application the background image showing with black line.

Comment: i am save my image like this my_image.9 @Der Golem

Comment: So. Make sure the black barker lines don't have any color immediately near them (the "border" has to be completely transparent + the BLACK patches - and the black has to be pure #ff000000). Tutorial: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: @Der Golem when i am using Android Asset Studio it's automatically save this extension

Comment: You have learn more here :http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 13):

You have uploaded that is not *.9.png image its .png image

In 9 patch its not black line its patch...

### 9 patch mechanism

Horizontal line shows the contain area and Vertical line shows the image will stretch from that area.

whenever you use 9 patch images, that line not appear in device..

In Your Image.

1) left Vertical Line indicates stretch Area. image will vertically(Height) stretch from that area

2) Top Horizontal Line  indicates stretch Area. image will Horizonatally(width) stretch from that area.

3) Bottom Horizontal Line indicates **text** contain Area(width).

4) Right Vertical Line indicates **text** contain Area(text can occupy that height only).